# Xamarin, Android: Build an alert with a checkbox and a "date-of-birth" wheel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I need to build an alert like this one:

```
        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.SetTitle("");

        alert.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.general_btn_newlevel);
        alert.SetMessage("");

        alert.SetPositiveButton("", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity_WelcomeKao2));
        });

        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
```

... I just need to display a check box there (for the user to accept the general terms of business) and some kind of "wheel" in which the user can choose his date of birth. I know this will probably need a custom alert however, I could not find anything about this in C #. Any help would be super awesome!
obs: This date of birth is to verify if you are of legal age.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a simple solution:

This bit of code:

```
        LayoutInflater lf = LayoutInflater.From(this);
        View mView = lf.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Alert_CheckBox, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


        alert.SetView(mView);
        alert.SetTitle("");


        alert.SetPositiveButton(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Finished), (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity_WelcomeKao2));
        });

        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
```

Together with the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/edt_checkbox_userinputalert"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Accept AGBs" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then just referencing the objects from the xml via mView.FindViewById<> ...

pretty simple actually.

So all I am doing is building the layout with the designer and then inflating it via the layoutInflater. No custom stuff neccessiary.

As for the date picker:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/pickers/date-picker